# How do I use Electron's showSaveDialog to set the destination of a cloned repo?

Tags: git, electron

I'm building an electron app that will allow users to clone repos they have access to.

I want to use showSaveDialog() to allow the user to select the destination of the cloned repo.

The code below clones a repo but in the app directory. I can set a default location easy enough, but I want the user to set the location.

How can I make the following work?

```
onClick={() =>
  dialog.showSaveDialog(
    {
      buttonLabel: 'Clone Repo',
    },
      cloneRepo(repo),
  )
}


export function cloneRepo(repo) {
  exec(`git clone ${repo.url}`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      console.log('stdout', stdout);
      console.log('error', error);
      console.log('stderr', stderr);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this:

```
onClick={() =>
  dialog.showSaveDialog(
    {
      defaultPath: service.url,
      buttonLabel: 'Clone Repo',
    },
    location => {
      cloneRepo(location, service);
    },
  )
}



export const cloneRepo = (location, repo) => {
  exec(`mkdir ${location}; cd ${location}; git clone ${repo.url}`);
};
```